# Python 3 : Time Difference : list comprehension of int VS list comprehension of list of int

Tags: python, time, list-comprehension

I had a problem with computation time in list comprehension. While solving it i find that :

```
In [209]: now = datetime.datetime.now()
     ...: for i in range(15):
     ...:     k = [0 for j in range(100000)]
     ...:     print(datetime.datetime.now() - now)
     ...:     
     0:00:00.004146
     0:00:00.007886
     0:00:00.011533
     0:00:00.015274
     0:00:00.019104
     0:00:00.022788
     0:00:00.026528
     0:00:00.030252
     0:00:00.033969
     0:00:00.037713
     0:00:00.041409
     0:00:00.045144
     0:00:00.048842
     0:00:00.052526
     0:00:00.056224
```

No problem : list comprehension is fast. Now instead of creating int, if we create list of int...

```
In [211]: now = datetime.datetime.now()
     ...: for i in range(15):
     ...:     k = [[0] for j in range(100000)]
     ...:     print(datetime.datetime.now() - now)
     ...:     
     0:00:00.047167
     0:00:00.107979
     0:00:00.170456
     0:00:00.231888
     0:00:00.293667
     0:00:00.354984
     0:00:06.686698    <=== Taking much more time
     0:00:06.747476
     0:00:06.811326
     0:00:06.874809
     0:00:06.937590
     0:00:06.998185
     0:00:07.068399
     0:00:13.449616    <=== Taking much more time
     0:00:13.511518
```

It looks like python needs to do some operation every X iterations. An operation that takes a lot of time here.

I suppose it has something to do with memory allocation or so on, but if someone that knows the why would like to explain it, I am more than interested !

Thank you.

Edit : More info : I have the problem in a tmux session, on ipython. If i open a new tmux window, on ipython the problem does not exist...
So it looks like the problem is linked to a specific open tmux window ? I still have the opened session, if some of you want to try few things...

So we say it is just corupted or is there something ?

Comment: Hmm... cannot reproduce on python3.6...

Comment: I can't reproduce it. The second way you are creating hundreds of thousands of lists which (I guess) may eventually have to be garbage collected, if you're short of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of measurement is not precise -- you have loads of overhead in function calls and `print` execution time will vary as you perform system calls. To have better results, try something like this:

```
import timeit
int_res = [timeit.timeit('[0 for i in x]', setup="x = range(100000)", number=1) for i in range(1000)]
list_res = [timeit.timeit('[[0] for i in x]', setup="x = range(100000)", number=1) for i in range(1000)]
print("Ints:", min(int_res), max(int_res))
print("Lists:", min(list_res), max(list_res))
```

Output:

```
Ints: 0.004607329028658569 0.04245903599075973
Lists: 0.015519230044446886 0.1320938270073384
```

As you can see, both methods show exactly the same behavior.

Then, I tried to test hypothesis about garbage collector. I did following:

```
import timeit
import gc
int_res = [timeit.timeit('[0 for i in x]', setup="x = range(100000); gc.collect()", number=1) for i in range(1000)]
list_res = [timeit.timeit('[[0] for i in x]', setup="x = range(100000); gc.collect()", number=1) for i in range(1000)]
print("Ints:", min(int_res), max(int_res))
print("Lists:", min(list_res), max(list_res))
```

Output:

```
Ints: 0.004779412993229926 0.02010424993932247
Lists: 0.015465378062799573 0.03042234410531819
```

Here, the `setup=` part is not measured and gives no effect. Each measurement performed with `timeit` function and then remembered.

Comment: Tested your functions. It is indeed from the garbage collector ! Thanks for the insight :)